# PHP log: Warning format

Tags: php, date, warnings, logging

The PHP log format does not include the date, for Warnings. For instance

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information...
```

does not have any date of when the warning happened.

Is there a way to change the Warning format, or at least have the date in the log?  (using`php-fpm` if it matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course always define your own error handler using [`set_error_handler`](http://www.php.net/set_error_handler). Simplified example:

```
function handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
    $message = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ": $errstr in $errfile at $errline\n";
    file_put_contents('error.log', $message, FILE_APPEND);
}

set_error_handler('handler');
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there something from the php.ini? The handler func / `set_error_handler` will be called all the time.

Comment: Not that I know, no. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php If your error handler is called all the time maybe you should fix your app. ;-P But even if it is, I don't see a big problem with it.

Comment: All the time means each script has to run it. Performance wise it is maybe not a big issue, but a global solution via `php.ini` would work for any application, even if they miss the `set_error_handler` call.